# Excel dynamic named range based on drop down result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges, xlookup

I have a table like this:

| Company | Department |
| --- | --- |
| Coke | Coke HR |
| Coke | Coke Sales |
| Mars | Mars HR |
| Mars | Mars Sales |

At the moment, I'm using dynamic named range formulas to generate in cell drop downs. The formulas are:

`=OFFSET(References!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(References!$A:$A)-1)`

`=OFFSET(References!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(References!$B:$B)-1)`

Ideally though, if Coke is selected in the first cell, then the seceond cell should only offer HR and Sales for coke in the second cell. I think I might need to add an xlookup function to the existing offset function to achieve this, but I'm really not sure. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Ps. Not wanting to use VBA or pivot tables as in other answers. Hoping for a formula only solution within Defined Names

Comment: INDIRECT is your friend for this. Sorry, I don't have the time to type a full answer but if you're happy with this link, I suspect it's going to do what you need. https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

**Functionality**

[image: Selecting Coke on left shows Coke options on right]

[image: Likewise, Mars left shows appropriate options right]

But wait, there' more!

[image: Blank cell right, appropriate options left]

[image: Coke option right, appropriate option [there's only one in this case, Coke] on the left]

[image: Likewise, Mars option right shows appropriate Mars option left]

*Added feature can removed v. easily: whilst lists depend upon one another in the context of associated elements, their functionality is completely 'modular' and independent...*

**Excel  Screenshot**

Ensuing material shall relate to tables/cells etc. within this screenshot:

[image: Main Screenshot - ensuing eqns. etc. shall refer to this]

OneDrive link to Excel spreadsheet: [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j961l_e8JiWPn7Dmlt?e=MUYL8v).

**Steps / fns to recreate **

1. Create 2nd lookup table per above

- Colour coding indicates corresponding cell for function text, e.g. G10 function to be entered into G5, H10 applicable for H5, etc.
- Advise setting up spreadsheet in exactly the same way I have at this stage (or simply download link above, your call)*

*Coke/Mars primary selection*

```
=IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(Range_beverage),"")
```

*Coke HR/Sales options*

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(R6C4:R9C4,R6C3:R9C3=RC[-1]))
```

2. Open Name Manager - you will create the following named ranges:

- Before doing this, go: Alt+ T + O (File, options), Formula, and Alt+R (i.e. select R1C! cell referencing as this will come in handy, you can change it back later)*

| Name | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| Range_primary1 | `=IF(MID(RC[1],1,SEARCH(" ",RC[1])-1)="Coke",R5C7,R6C7)` |
| Range_beverage | `=R5C7:R6C7` |
| Range_primary | `=IF(RC[1]<>"",Range_primary_1, Range_beverage)` |
| SubRange_Mars | `=R6C8:R6C9` |
| SubRange_Coke | `=R5C8:R5C9` |
| SubRange | `=IF(R5C[-1]="Mars",SubRange_Mars,SubRange_Coke)` |

- You can include more robust means for referencing these cells dynamically later as req.
- Note on validation lists: cannot use a function that references a range; cannot use a named range with such a function (1 removed), but '2 removed' works (i.e. reference named range that references another range with function)

3. Insert two validation lists directly adjacent to one another (per yellow shaded cells in main spreadsheet screenshot above) as follows:

a) Alt + d + L (or however you do with a mouse) - remove *Input Message* and *Error Alert* options per screenshots below:

[image: Data Validation Input and Error Alert options]

**Specifying validation list sources**

And not for the moment we've all been waiting for...

[image: Left and Right Validation List functions]

i.e. sources as follows:

*List on left (i.e. Coke / Mars):*

```
=Range_primaray
```

*Right list (HR/Sales for Coke/Mars resp.)*:

```
=SubRange
```

Another funny little Microsoft/Office 'bug' I need to chat to Bill about: open up the validation list dialogue browsers after completing final step above, and just double-check the Input Error / Alert message options are still disabled.  I've known them to mischievously revert back (unless it allows you to deselect even though it will only store your selections once something has changed int eh restaurant portion of the validation dialogue tabbed menu window...

ANYWAYS,  go well, go shell. - hope this works out for you! :)